# Empty Value for $_POST variable in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord, post

I have a form :

```
       <?php
            $attr = array('id'=>'urlSubmit');
            $urlInputAttr = array('name'=>'urlInput','value'=>'yourdomain.com','maxlength'=>'50','size'=>'25');
            echo form_open('urlSubmission',$attr);
            echo form_input($urlInputAttr);
            #echo form_submit('urlInput', '');
            echo form_close();
        ?>

a controller called **urlsubmission**

    # Determine whether domain already has been crawled.
                $this->load->model('domaincheckmodel');

                    $this->domaincheckmodel->verifyduplicates();
```

and a function within a model(domaincheckmodel) which basically checks for duplicate records and inserts a new domain:

```
function verifyduplicates(){
        # $_POSTed value of urlInput
        $tldEntered = $this->input->post('urlInput'); ## echo out $_POSTed domain entered.
        ## Gather if the domain exists in db
        $DupDomains = $this->db->get_where('ClientDomain', array('tld'=>$tldEntered));   // Get ClientDomain table

    if($DupDomains->num_rows() > 0 ){
        $this->load->view('err/domainexists'); ##domain already used
    }

    # else, no domain present, insert.
    else{
        #array of insert values:
        $insertNewDomain = array('tld'=>$tldEntered);
        $this->db->insert('ClientDomain', $insertNewDomain); 
        $this->load->view('success/domainfree'); ##domain is free and has not been entered.
    }
```

Problem is: when I submit, it submits a record to the database but `tld` is empty.

Comment: How do you submit? There is no submit button in your code.

Comment: I see you posted with the same function in a question a while ago... did you re-install the CI app and now it's not posting?

Comment: Its no longer throwing an error, after using `$this->input->post('urlInput');`  instead of `$_POST['urlInput']` but its now submitting a record, but `tld` field in db is blank.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function verifyduplicates(){
    #PREPARE DATA
    if ($this->input->post('name_of_your_button')){
        $postedTLD = $this->input->post('urlInput');    // Get unsanitized data
        echo $postedTLD;
        $this->db->set('tld', $postedTLD); // AutoMagically escaped by AR
        #INSERT DATA
        $this->db->insert('ClientDomain'); 
    }
}
```

just make sure that you have name your submit button

Comment: Does the name field of submit need to have the same "name" like `<input type="submit" name="urlInput" />` ?

Comment: you may name it any name you want. for example the name is submit_button then $this->input->post('submit_button'), you can  name it urlInput as long as it is unique

Comment: This still is submitting a empty value

Comment: what are you inserting to clientDomain?