# Codeigniter issue with submitted variables as blank

Tags: php, forms, codeigniter, post, http-post

I have a form :

```
   <?php
        $attr = array('id'=>'urlSubmit');
        $urlInputAttr = array('name'=>'urlInput','value'=>'yourdomain.com','maxlength'=>'50','size'=>'25');
        echo form_open('urlSubmission',$attr);
        echo form_input($urlInputAttr);
        #echo form_submit('urlInput', '');
        echo form_close();
    ?>
```

a controller called **urlsubmission**

```
       $this->load->model('domaincheckmodel');

            $this->domaincheckmodel->verifyduplicates($this->input->post('urlInput'));
```

and a function within a model(domaincheckmodel) which basically checks for duplicate records and inserts a new domain:

```
   function verifyduplicates($tldEntered){
    # $_POSTed value of urlInput
    ## Gather if the domain exists in db
    $DupDomains = $this->db->get_where('ClientDomain', array('tld'=>$tldEntered));

        if($DupDomains->num_rows() > 0 ){
            $this->load->view('err/domainexists'); ##domain already used
        }

        # else, no domain present, insert.
        else{
            #array of insert values:
            $insertNewDomain = array('tld'=>$this->input->post('urlInput',TRUE));
            $this->db->insert('ClientDomain', $insertNewDomain); 
            $this->load->view('success/domainfree'); ##domain is free and has been entered.
        }
    }
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Empty Value for $\_POST variable in codeigniter](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14492872/empty-value-for-post-variable-in-codeigniter)

Comment: See declaration of $DupDomains

Comment: You don't need to set an attribute 'method' => 'post' as automatically CI's form_open() uses POST as Method

Comment: ^^ this is true, but doesn't affect an empty value being sent. Anyone see anything wrong here? Additionally, I added an img of what is being stored upon submit in the db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$this->domaincheckmodel->verifyduplicates($this->input->post('urlInput')); 



function verifyduplicates($tldEntered){
    # $_POSTed value of urlInput
    ## Gather if the domain exists in db
    $DupDomains = $this->db->get_where('ClientDomain', array('tld'=>$tldEntered));
```

You're passing from the form to the controller to the model, are you sure the post variable is staying populated? Try the above, capture the post variable in the controller and pass it to the model instead of trying to read it in the model itself?

A little clarification on passing parameters to functions. You can do this via whatever is inside the brackets as follows.

Controller:

```
$myVariable = $this->someModel->someFunction($someParameter)
```

Model:

```
function someFunction($variableIWantToPopulateWithSomeParameter)
```

So someParameter gets passed from the controller to the function name in the model. There is one thing to be aware of though and that is that model function now EXPECTS a parameter and if you don't give it one, ie you call someFunction() you'll get an error. This can be avoided by giving it a default value like this:

```
function someFunction($myVariable = 1)
```

What that is going to do is say if I don't get a value passed to me I am going to make $myVariable equal to one, if I do I'll overwrite 1 with the new value. So if you send two calls to that function this is what you can expect:

```
//$myVariable is going to be 1, the default.
```

$this->someModel->someFunction();

```
//$myVariable is going to be 5, the value passed to it
```

$this->someModel->someFunction(5);

Comment: Can you please show me what you mean by " pass it to the model instead of trying to read it in the model itself " ?

I understand what you mean by  capture the post variable in the controller.

Thanks!

Comment: I did. The first line captures the post variable in the controller then passes it in the model call. If you look at the model it is expecting that parameter and populates $tldEntered with the variable the controller passed it. Those are the only two lines you'll need to change. Well that and remove the line in the model that tries to populate $tldEntered from the post variable.

Comment: How does the model know? the first line $this->domaincheckmodel->verifyduplicates($this->input->post('urlInput')); isn't assigned a variable of $tldEntered in your code above. Does that make sense ?

Comment: yeah, if you look at the function line for the model it has $tldEntered in the brackets. That means it is populating that variable with whatever it's passed. So for example let's say you want to check a specific user on your database, in your controller you could make a call to the model with $this->users->getUser($userId) the userId gets sent as a parameter to the model, then in the model the function would be function getUser($userId) whatever variable name you have in the brackets in the model function name.

Comment: Makes sense, appreciate you explaining that. See my updated code, it still isn't populating the field in the db after making the changes. I'm simply trying to get the domain (e.g. tld) in the database to have the value stored upon submit. Any thoughts?

Comment: updated my answer with some clarification on what we were discussing. Now, on to the problem, are you positive the post variable actually has anything in it? Try print_r($this->input->post) in the controller before making the model call. Because honestly everything else looks fine =/

Comment: print_r($this->input->post()); isn't printing out anything. Would it make more sense to make this into a $_SESSION var if this value initially inputted will be used for a few pages ?

Comment: Hey man - thanks so much for your help - this came down to a stupid environment issue (sheesh) - thanks :)